# Vega-lite: Mark text overlaps top axis

Tags: vega-lite, vega

How can fix text overlap on the top axis in the example?

[vega-lite example](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoTAE8ccNAEYl23ZdRWADC4C%20Ck%20YcAmWzr1oYi5O7p4WaADMfvbWwSEeIGbhqAAs0QGOQW4JSQ5i6Q7O2WEOAGwFsW4Auu4ggkimcABORqDITQDWaCBMSC2hIO1dmole3ZhwAB6YiiBIsmSCPgDsTko6NGTy6EsAZjNKvRBwwrIOgzTKykuzypOBtXCyUGzKNAtooKafILs0J8punYArUJtMfn8AUD-JYlLlurI2Ah3jpZrs2E1kDN0ApAa58VUlE8Xm8PiN7iNIYJAeh4etJjQDCMMf9ZNjEmwcCB8UpvpT-tToTE4WN0ABHBjzTB0NQ0Ujc-FAA)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBMkUANZkATmwbiAJmhAB3GHTjSQOJBo01xZNAJnwaZLGgBMABhcyImAJ4AbQ%20ig4Hx8jDSRMFFQAbVBxJAR-EDEGZUCAfRcjYiQfBjgINBiQbxx-AEYZbNzytxcAXylQEv8nSpy861qGpq9StABmNuq0Mtr6xuLe-wAWIY7UMoEuiebrOZq3bsm%201AA2dZGugF0tuITtMIi0sqNk1MS79MyZTGUkcQgAMzZlBEKenZJCKKIwqNQ4JheQrbQxHGSfGhBLToKodDw-TBoUAIpGFOEgH4aODKPENEBIArRECouBpTxIZSY9ZpOCaED4tifT4QOCY9AAL2JbBAW1W6ARPkwxKMcAAHjgSegaBAAGo5GgaAAUlwYCCiAB1qe04IajgBKAAEADIrRblQAxCwGTUAah1esNNNNZpFJwmZ0SlyQaSctzU920j1pz2Kbw%2031%20-xh2glUpJMjlCu0yrVPg12vCuoNRuq3uttodTqlrvdxa97J9oqm2jlUvETJAOJ8yJLaKS9jiIXQXjSGjYyAsvrq%20IgA5ylKKAe0srpUpwWWNznGsXiiR0GvoRgYOEuiTkmggJkC2vHSAsmoA5LKH2bKH5LPQpBaXJQKt-KC4AiWgAVBaK6eHA66nLu2gjmOE7iGkCCTjIx6nrBo63hYUQuEcIr%20jBw6YQhSFILKR4nuEiRwVh4hRGURwWqBZSUE4Ai%20jIyDKAoC47uc6A%20EgXjEhkpHcQULzNugyhwFAHaeL4-hRLIDLsvCqh-KgoBBhc4TBjcZKslAbBEliIBoVRZkSkOoA0toADE0xQAA7AAHEgrn4eSyg0EgABKbB%20AAIvkUA%20TgmDsJIWm9meqlkkS0DhZFEhmbOZCDtohrNKgFqGhaLoWpqObqlqtbZVMZYAPwWuVMKmhauWGoabqFh69UNgVeUgAA3BaNJNSAXWagmyCYAWmBFp6xqml%20zUgGajYyORMXQDkiTkfCiLdtoqxkvuGiHqtUDrcuRjnsiZRklCx2ncORhdj2NIsmy12hrdfiwQ921Pcaq4MpidRA9B-EgIJwnKNcYk8UYYrFK2tzeJ9VJSrKmL4p8GlmTp6BBiGXlGSZ-igBZUpmeqGVmXZAlwJ8gMyHIPJ5uIxOxdoyFmJ9CUrbZm6oAIZLvGQyO88MqBOM54ydjQwRU3zsiCSCCWhclUVpXOQ4gBVpSDcNJV5mVbXFs01W1Ub2smuyjXdS1dUm51hWGn1A3dcNo3hBNU2xbNNsLUtIA80kJ3IwH324ugqwM%208yI-gLMg3aAa0h1CW3h2zZKo3yicaymPxjZ77X1nC3VSBohqNsDM7B-kSZLugm3JugF2hLRVk-bxIA453enXGHO0R82Wxd3joap-3ybTuijJoK8eRknGZCsxB66rTn9erpBIpkiYZgWGQACS4gs4qP4VMYpjmJYADyDBpmgP6ASD1Gw1JYMWHAqkyPBd7RUU6WZURb%20FgkKTi2P-HIGEgGIWQORSeIAF5KWzhlCB6A7AOHprhGQ4gaCBBnsoPIMhBSqDwXPfEZEa7RETtXL6MgfiInbNoPwdNQQ%20Q0AAZWofXFhGoSFwBeDghQABhNQDDV7IM1oEGWmo0FYAINMFw-soFoE%20POPhYMkBMCCJSFRPgeQyAZL5ZRqjOJkQAKJo1ZHydwIBkLiHMW2Kx-DFDaOMSAfkFgiQrW3EHO6odaE%20UsbtNg64ZAqB4agHRejih0BDpHdRmifAAEE8yUxpswmQgkEmJMsMjCW1jMlBAAEIUiCO-dmGoNCfUIR4uU98wGcJACnAkATRFg1ph2MJyJIlqMipgEOdkMkaKCFfUgyhBIr1nj0gRwj1BZ37OI7QkifDSLgPYWR8j-buM0LU1A9QThAA) is what I ended up with.

Now, you will probably not like how I got there. In the editor I went to the **Compiled Vega** tab and edited the low-level Vega spec. The fix was:

1. Add a signal with the `extent` transform:

   `{"type": "extent", "field": "value", "signal": "y_domain"}`
2. Derive two more signals from it:

   ```
   {"name": "y_domain_min", "update": "y_domain[0]"},
   {"name": "y_domain_max", "update": "y_domain[1] * 1.25"}
   ```

   Note the multiplier.
3. Use the new signals for the domain definition.

   ```
   {
     "name": "y",
     "type": "linear",
     "domain": [{"signal": "y_domain_min"}, {"signal": "y_domain_max"}],
     ...
   ```

If a fix is possible directly in Vega-lite, I'd like to know.

Comment: It looks interesting but this complicates things a lot. If you add 2 characters to "value" the problem will come back